# Django_filters gives an error "QuizFilter has no len()"

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I have one filter:

```py
import django_filters

from .models import Quiz


class QuizFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = ['title', 'level']
```

```py
class QuizList(ListView):
    """List of quizzes + pagination"""
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'quizapp/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'quizzes'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        filtered_quizzes = QuizFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return filtered_quizzes
```

**When I open the page I got this error:**

[image]

**In templates I just write {% for quiz in quizzes.qs %} and for filtering I use {{ quizzes.form.as_p }}

How can I solve the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You here return the `QuizFilter`, not its filtered queryset. You need to return the `.qs` attribute of the `QuizFilter`:

```
class QuizList(ListView):
    """List of quizzes + pagination"""
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'quizapp/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'quizzes'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        filtered_quizzes = QuizFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return filtered_quizzes.qs
```

If you need access to the filter as well, it might be better to make use of a `FilterView`:

```
class QuizList(ListView):
    """List of quizzes + pagination"""
    model = Quiz
    template_name = 'quizapp/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'quizzes'
    paginate_by = 15

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = self.model.objects.all()
        filtered_quizzes = QuizFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=qs)
        return filtered_quizzes.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            filter=QuizFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.model.objects.all())
        )
        return context
```

So then you can render the filter with `{{ filter.form.as_p }}`.

Comment: It's ok, But I need to use filter form in a template. {{ quizzes.form.as_p }}. If I'll return the filtered_quizzes.qs I'll can't use a form.

Comment: @Hahan't: then you need to pass this in the context, for example by updating the `get_context_data` method.

Comment: @Hahan't: it might however be better to use a `FilterView` here.